# AJAX works on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: jquery

OK, I have this HTML code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.3.2.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js" ></script>
</head>

<body> 

    <div>
    <a><div id= "0" class="Button" href="./es/uno.xml">uno</div></a>
    <a ><div id= "1" class="Button" href="./es/dos.xml">dos</div></a>
    <a ><div id= "2" class="Button" href="./es/tres.xml">tres</div></a>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <div id="content" class="content">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.Button').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        if( typeof href != "undefined" && href != ""){
            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                            //alert($(data).contents().contents().text());
                            $('#content').html(data);
                            ultXML = href;
                        }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The above code let me load 3 diferents xml files with no tags at all in the div content. It works OK on Firefox but it doesn t work on Chrome (Neither Wind or Ubuntu Chromium)

Comment: The only thing I don't like there is the "typeof" part. Href will be either a string or empty, so I dont see the point in that. The rest looks just fine

Answer (score 2):

Change the if conditions to `if(href) { ...`. 
You are checking if the value is undefined or an empty string, both will evaluate to false if you do `if(href) { ...`.

I am using chrome in windows right now, and your code seems to work (of course it throws me a 404 error cause i don't have the files).

If that didn't solve your problem, try to open the Chrome developer tools and check if in "Network" you see the ajax request.

Update: added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YuFyd/) with a blank alert on ajax success

Comment: I really don t understand I delete almost everything. I just let a alert("hello"); in the success function! But it display on FF not on Chrome.

Comment: I also delete the if sentence and download the newest jquery.1.7.2.min.js but still not working. I must be doing a very stupid newbie error! :S

Comment: I made a jsfiddle using the ajax echo api, try it out. Do you see any error message in the developer tools console?

Answer (score 0):

I finally discover what was the stupid newbie error! The code has nothing wrong is working well. The problem was when I was testing it locally:

file:///home/.../index.html (navigation browser bar)

FF can find the path of ./es/uno.xml but (i dint know why) Chrome can not. So it replace the DIV content with nothing.

It works ok if I put the files in a server to access it in the way:

http://example.com

Thanks Everybody!